# Obter elemento sem id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, canvas

Tenho uma `div`, e dentro dela **um** `canvas` sem `id` e **outros elementos**.

```
<div id="itens">
   ...
   <canvas></canvas>
   ...
</div>
```

Como posso obter **o** `canvas` usando `JQuery`?

Comment: $("#itens canvas") ou document.getElementsByTagName("canvas") seria isso somente ?

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman, formate como resposta seu comentário! :)

Comment: O único problema é que em ambos os casos eles não trazem o objeto canvas em si. No primeiro caso, ele traz um objeto jquery com um array de canvas, no segundo caso ele também traz um array de canvas, logo se tenho `var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");` para poder trabalhar com o `canvas` obtido devo usar `canvas[0]`. Gostaria de algo que me trouxesse o primeiro canvas de uma vez só.

Comment: obter o array de canvas pode ser util se você quiser atribuir um style, ou outra propriedade a todos os canvas de uma vez só

Comment: @PedroLaini você tem razão! Neste caso funcionaria perfeitamente as duas opções muito bem dadas pelo ThiagoFriedman, mas é que no meu caso só existe um canvas mesmo, e preciso trabalhar com as propriedades dele, sendo assim, a resposta postada pelo PedroLaini resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Se você precisa dos canvas dentro do elemento** `#itens`

1) `$('#itens canvas')` seleciona todos os `canvas` dentro do elemento `$itens`

2a) Para retornar apenas o primeiro **(ou único)** utilize `$('#itens canvas').get(0)` ou `$('#itens canvas')[0]`

2b) Ou, conforme sugerido por @JefersonAssis nos comentários:

> $('#itens canvas:first-child')

**Se você quer todos os elementos canvas**

1) `$('canvas')` seleciona todos os canvas na página

2a) Para retornar apenas o primeiro **(ou único)** utilize `$('canvas').get(0)` ou  `$('canvas')[0]`

2b) Ou, conforme sugerido por @JefersonAssis nos comentários:

> $('#itens canvas:first-child')

Comment: E se eu quiser obter unicamente o primeiro canvas?

Comment: respondido a pergunta

Comment: Só complementando a resposta do Pedro, você pode usar os seletores `:first-child`, ficaria assim: `$('#itens canvas:first-child')`.

Comment: incluido na resposta